# Center align div to the bottom of scrollable div

Tags: html, css, alignment

```
<div class="chat-space">

    <ol id="chat" class="discussion">
        <!-- Chat messages get added here -->
    </ol>

    <div id="chat-box">
        <input id="message"></input>
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>       
</div>
```

How can I have the `chat-box div` to the bottom of the `chat-space div` at all times and centred as well, the `chat-space div` becomes scrollable as chat messages arrive and I would like to be able to scroll through the messages having the `input` sticked to the bottom.

This is the CSS code for the `chat-space` div :

```
.chat-space {
    background-color: #4B6B8B;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it as absolute position, and set up the `bottom` value. And simply use `text-align:center` to center the elements inside.

```
#chat-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

To have the scroll bar working properly, you could set the `overflow` property on `#chat`.

```
#chat {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9wuyzznL/4/

Comment: I've tried this and when I scroll up the input box scrolls up as well, it doesn't stay at the bottom...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.chat-space{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px;
}

ol {
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.chat-box {
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  background:#ccc;
  border-top:1px solid #333;
  padding:5px;
}

button {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:none;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

input{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-space">

    <ol id="chat" class="discussion">
        
      <li>Message 1</li>
      <li>Message 2</li>
      <li>Message 3</li>
      <li>Message 4</li>
      <li>Message 5</li>
      <li>Message 6</li>
      <li>Message 7</li>
      <li>Message 8</li>
      <li>Message 9</li>
      <li>Message 10</li>
      <li>Message 11</li>
      <li>Message 12</li>
      <li>Message 13</li>
    </ol>

    <div id="chat-box">
        <input id="message"></input>
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: this works but the input box is not centred at the bottom, what should i add?